# view.element.find not working in fullcalendar v.2

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've eventRender function to change day background for specific classname.

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {              
    if (event.className == 'booked') {
        var dateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        view.element.find('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#FAA732');                        
    }               
},
```

This function working properly on fullcalendar 1.6.4 but not in version 2.1 (I already change date conversion to moment).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined fullcalendar
```

Another problem is, this function only change the background of event start, not the whole date of an event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Is no longer needed and doesn't work in 2.*. This is because `event.start` is already a [`momentjs`](http://momentjs.com/) object. You can simply use

```
event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

As for `view.element`, it was replaced by `view.el[0]`, so you should use

```
$(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString + ']')
```

to change the specific day.

Your `eventRender` will become

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    var dateString = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    $(view.el[0]).find('.fc-day[data-date=' + dateString + ']')
                .css('background-color', '#FAA732');
},
```

For the complete code check the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/666uvdcj/2/).

Comment: I need to change the background of the day, not the event. Check this => http://jsfiddle.net/gx2Lu06f/. Its working on 1.6.4 version, but not 2.1

Comment: Check the updated answer an JSfiddle that does what you need.

Comment: Do you have solution for my other problem? I want to change the background to the whole event, not just the day at event start. For example at http://jsfiddle.net/k4p1od5z/, you could see at event 3, I want the background also applied until 19th September